# get the row id of an spinner item populated from database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have a spinner witch is populated from database, when  I select an item ,i would like  to return the row id (the primary key) of this item in the database;
this is my code:

```
private int getcategoryrowid(Spinner spinner){                  

        AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

        // Then we need to get a readable database
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();


        //
        Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor) (spinner.getSelectedItem());
        String t=String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println(t);
        int rowid = cursor1.getInt(cursor1.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        System.out.println(rowid);
         cursor1.close();
         sqliteDatabase.close();
        return rowid;
```

}

and this the logcat:

```
06-14 16:02:01.840: W/dalvikvm(14081): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at com.app.pfe.Addfile.getcategoryrowid(Addfile.java:345)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at com.app.pfe.Addfile.onClick(Addfile.java:85)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 16:02:01.880: E/AndroidRuntime(14081):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: `Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor) (spinner.getSelectedItem());` WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have a whole separate class?  You can get it from the `onItemSelected` method, since it gives it to you in the parameters coming in (it's the `long id` part)...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            long rowId = id;    
    }
});
```

Comment: thaannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnks,it is very helpful,

Comment: how can I get the value of rowId, I use long id=rowid but it say me that rowId cannot be resolved to a variable,what I do to return this value

Comment: You've got it backwards, id is already declared and is passed into the method.  You need to set it to a variable of your own.  My example declared the variable rowId, and then set it equal to id (which is the database row id passed in by the framework).  Then you use rowId.  If you need it outside the `onItemSelected` method, create the `rowId` as a class variable.

Comment: Sory, I can't andrestand you very much; but i create a global vraible rawid then after this code i set rowid=rowId but it return me 0 alltime , it seems that the setOnItemSelectedIstener does not be executed , Idon't khow why

Comment: No.  In the `onItemSelected` method set your global variable to equal `id`.  So you would have `yourVariable = id;`.  And it should change each time you change your spinner selection (as long as your db is set up properly with a column called `_id` and that column is in your cursor, which I assume it is because the framework will complain if it isn't and you haven't mentioned that).

Comment: yes i do that and this is my code filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       }
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
              throwid = (int)id;  
             System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
       }
   });///I use system.out.println to affich the  row id but I have nothing in the logcat it seems that the code doesn't be executed

Answer (score 1):

Create a Context of the Activity on top

```
public Context cntx = this;
```

now add cntx as Below:

```
AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(cntx);
```